# Why don't they use more than 12v in high power car audio?

Tags: audio, power-electronics

In every single high-powered car audio system I've seen, in person and on the internet, the amplifier has been run off of the main 12 volt power system.

Such systems feature multiple parallel runs of heavy-gauge (Commonly 2 AWG or lower) wire between the battery and amplifiers and several alternators in parallel to supply the required current, which is in the hundreds-of-amps range. For a 5KW system, the maximum current would be around 400 amps.

Additionally, modern class D subwoofer amplifiers often have easily 2/3 of the internal space dedicated to converting the ultra-high-current 12 volt input up to a higher voltage, typically 70-100 volts, to drive the subwoofers.

Instead of using the 12v and boosting it, an alternative approach would be to have the alternators wired in series or using higher turn count windings to generate a higher voltage (70-100 volts as above) and run the output stage directly off of that. It would be a much simpler setup, as you could omit the voltage booster section of the amplifier and would only need the output stage and signal processing.

Why isn't the latter setup used in high-power car audio systems?

[Edit] For clarification, I am not concerned with "normal" (~1kw or less) car audio setups. I'm asking about competition builds where they are using extremely high amounts of power and are so weighted down with equipment that their primary purpose is to make noise and set SPL records, not be everyday commuting vehicles.

Comment: Primary function of an automobile is not its audio. Audio systems use 12 V because the primary voltage in autos is 12V. Instead of having losses in a booster, you will have losses in down-converter to 12V battery, unless you re-design the entire system to run on 24 V or 48 V or whatever. Until there will be compelling economical reasons to re-design all automobiles into higher voltage, your "hybrid" proposal" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Do these competitions have any regulations? Such as system voltage....

Comment: @SolarMike Good point, many car audio competitions have classes and max voltage limits, such a system would have to be in the "unlimited" class in most competitions.

Comment: @ThorLancaster Hmm. So what happens when a Prius Plug-In Hybrid is being used in competition? The battery voltage can be from either one 346 V system or two 207.2 V systems. Just curious.

Comment: Are you proposing the entire vehicle's power system operates at the new higher voltage? Or running a completely separate power system for the power stage of your gear?

Comment: @jonk If you were using a hybrid, such a system would make sense, especially with the modern high voltage MOSFETs they have nowadays. You'd have to make your own class D amplifier, but with the right design you'd be able to blow every other setup away in terms of raw power.

Comment: @ThorLancaster You make me wonder (I'm not seriously interested, though) about using the existing motor driver circuits in the car as parts for the final amplifier output stage. With the safety features of the circuit disabled, It should be able to slug speakers around just fine. Makes me wonder if any of this has already been done, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bass drops and batteries.**

There is only one way to handle an instantaneous power spike that exceeds the capacity of the alternator, and that is to draw it from the battery.

If you were to rebuild your secondary alternator to produce 100 volts (completely possible), and then purchase and install gear that used that for power, if you do not subsequently attach a battery bank that is rated for that same voltage (or boosted to pretend to have that voltage), then you only have the output from that one alternator. Period. Exceeding its capacity will break it.

In the current method, you have access to the output of both alternators and the battery that already had to be there for the car to start, and you didn't have to buy a second battery or the booster to make it play nice with a 100 volt system. Doing what you propose halves your available power and requires at least one additional battery or battery bank.

Comment: That is why they put those large pretty capacitors on the power supply - so the battery and alternator don’t have to deal with those surges...

Comment: @Solar Mike, you're definitely right! Except that enthusiast and competitive builds frequently consume more average instantaneous power than the alternators can produce, especially so when the volume is cranked up. The deficit is paid by the battery.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.lifewire.com/car-audio-capacitors-explained-534564

Comment: @SolarMike, yes. And if the power draw of the gear is, on average, greater than the capacity of the alternator, if there is no battery attached, the entire system will brown out and the alternator may break. Sir.

Comment: Sir, if the capacitors are the closest to the amp cf alternator & battery then the power will come from the capacitor... less resistance between amp and capacitor cf amp and alternator or battery.. Why don't you like the capacitors?

Comment: @SolarMike, they do exactly what you say, and nothing else. They do not actually add available power capacity, and these builds almost always use more power than the alternators provide, and they do so continuously. Batteries are, for the duration of their charge, actually creating power - mostly to charge said capacitors. It's not a matter of not liking them. We're talking about different phenomena at this point.

Comment: The alternators create the power (by converting it from the rotational motion of the engine) which is then stored in either the batteries or the capacitors...  Batteries do not "create"power as you seem to think re "Batteries are, for the duration of their charge, actually creating power"...

Comment: @SolarMike - you can disagree with the verb all you like, but power - literally the expression of a transfer in joules per second - only exists at the moment it is created, and ceases when the transfer stops. That's EE101. If you prefer a different verb for what a battery does when it outputs 50 amps at 12 volts for 20 minutes during a performance, you're welcome to use that instead.

Comment: It's a chemical reaction providing that energy...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93520/discussion-between-sean-boddy-and-solar-mike).

Comment: Now I see where you're going, you'd need to buy/build a large secondary battery pack (likely LiFePO4) to allow the battery system to cope with the bass drops.

Comment: @ThorLancaster, and anytime the total power output exceeded the capacity of your (now just one) alternator, yes. Especially in an extreme build, if they run at full output for too long, the battery can trickle out and things get bad. For a secondary system, without that battery, the amplifier will probably just shut down on undervoltage. You'd be better off rebuilding the entire system to use a higher voltage - it would keep access to both alternators and the existing battery.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what class of car design you look at.  There are many with higher power than the 12V bridge amplifiers.

**I think your premises are false therefore the conclusion is also.**
If you are the rare person that needs 6kW 100V generator for an audio system, add a 2nd alternator.

[Here](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP11769) is one such IC for that market.

> The PMP11769 reference design is a complete solution for a 700W automotive external amp. The boost converter provides 36.0V @ 10.0A continuous / 20.0A peak from an input voltage of 9-16V. It contains two premium Class-D audio amplifiers, which provide 2x 175W @ 4-Ω load (left & right channel) and 1x 350W @ 2-Ω (subwoofer).The design is well suited for car audio external amp applications due to its thin profile and high power output.

- Interleaved Synchronous Boost + Audio Amplifier
- Output   36.0V @ 10.0A (continuous) / 20.0A (peak)
- Free-Running switching frequency of 250 kHz CCM
- one TPA3251D2 in stereo mode  (175W 4Ω )
- one TPA3251D2 in mono mode subwoofer (350W 2Ω)
- -12.0V @ 50mA) with LM2841X-Q, +3.3V @ 50mA) with TPS7A6633-Q
- ~> 95% efficient 3~10A
- 0.6% V overshoot 10A to 20A